# In Transformers (2007) movie, why are they stuck in traffic waiting to be attacked?

Tags: transformers-2007

In Transformers, Sector Seven decided to work with the Autobots. They need to bring the All-Spark to a safe place, but then they get stuck in traffic. This could and should have been prevented in several ways.

They could have used sirens to navigate through the traffic quickly, or they could have air lifted the All-Spark I realize they might be trying to be discrete, but come on. They are in a big city, where there are many accidents that are already have emergency vehicles racing to the scene, and then we have the Autobots stuck in traffic.

Honestly, it seems like these people do not have any common sense. Because they also have Sam running through downtown on foot, when he could be in a transforming car and get to the building faster and safer. Like in the second movie, when Sam had to run across the desert on foot in the middle of a war zone, again he could have been in a transforming car.

Anyways, they are trying get their destination quickly, why are they stuck in traffic?

Comment: Do you really expect common sense in a Michael Bay film? Heck, even Star Trek characters don't use common sense quite often (the so called idiot plots).

Comment: as far as i know the transformers can't fully transform with people in it. so perhaps not to split it

Comment: @Sarfaraaz that is not true. It has been shown in movies that the transformers *transform* with humans in them.

Comment: @Shreedhar this is more what i meant. "they can't keep people inside them like gundam pilots" [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfYoRKLzJXw)

Comment: Google maps were down at the moment...

Comment: Is the answer that we need to see a sexy woman running in super slow motion?